# Can we access DataStore from google apps scripts?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to import data from flat files stored in Google Drive into DataStore. Then use the full-text search and other query options to analyze the data using apps-script.

The script API doc shows how we can access Google Drive data from the apps-script.

Now, is there any API in apps-script to access DataStore from the scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google provides a (beta) [REST API](https://developers.google.com/datastore) to access your data.  Steps to enable [are here](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/activate#google_cloud_datastore_for_accessing_existing_app_engine_datastore_from_other_platform).

However, BigQuery is usually better for the type of analysis you describe. See:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, you should consider writing your own Web Service to get you access to the DataStore. You can then access that Web Service hosted in your App Engine application from your App Scripts. A detailed example is provided over [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/appengine).

Additionally, the [Cloud DataStore](https://developers.google.com/datastore/) is now provided under the Google Cloud Platform and while it is still in preview, there is an API available to interact with the Datastore. This API is exhaustive and allows for both read and write operations. But keep in mind that it is currently under Preview.